# Enterprise find files (via powershell) exclude Tempory Internet Files

Tags: powershell, command-line, dir, findstr

I am trying to run this command via powershell on every computer on my network.

I am running into a problem with Temporary Internet Files, providing too many false positives.

Can anyone suggest a way to improve this command?

```
dir C:\Users\ /S /B | findstr /i "".t.st."" > "C:\test.txt"
```

One suggestion, was

```
dir C:\Users\ /S /B | findstr /i "".t.st."" > "C:\test.txt"
dir C:\Users\ /S /B | findstr /i "".t.st."" | findstr ""Temporary Internet Files"" > "C:\test2.txt"
fc C:\test.txt C:\test2.txt > C:\results.txt
```

But running through tests, it didn't give me the results I was looking for. I still had duplications. Or it would say the files are too different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this through PowerShell then why not use PowerShell commands? Your examples are using the legacy DIR command. You could use Get-ChildItem instead. You can use -Exclude to skip a folder. You could use -filter or -include to find the files you want. Worse case is to get the files and then pipe to where object perhaps using a regex pattern to filter out the files you want. I can't tell from your commands what files you are looking for.

Comment: get-childitem c:\users -recurse -exclude "\Temporary Internet Files"